# Error when mocking interfaces in PHP using Mockery

Tags: php, laravel, mockery

I have run into a problem when mocking Interfaces using Mockery in PHP (im using the laravel framework but I'm not sure this is relevant.

I have defined an interface

```
<?php namespace MyNamespace\SomeSubFolder;

interface MyInterface {

    public function method1();

}
```

And I have a class that typehints that interface on one of the methods...

```
<?php namespace MyNamespace\SomeSubFolder;

use MyNamespace\SomeSubFolder\MyInterface;

class MyClass {

    public function execute(MyInterface $interface)
    {
         //does some stuff here

    }
}
```

...and I am trying to test MyClass. I have created a test that looks something like this:

```
public function testExecute()
{

    $mock = Mockery::mock('MyNamespace\SomeSubFolder\MyInterface');

    $mock->shouldReceive('method1')
         ->andReturn('foo');

    $myClass = new MyClass();

    $myClass->execute($mock);

}
```

When I run the test I receive the message

'ErrorException: Argument 1 passed to MyClass::execute must be an instance of MyNamespace\SomeSubFolder\MyInterface, instance of Mockery_123465456 given....'

I have no idea why.

Within the test I have tried the following :

```
$this->assertTrue(interface_exists('MyNamespace\SomeSubFolder\MyInterface'));

$this->assertTrue($mock instanceof MyInterface);
```

and both return true, so it appears as if I have created and instance that implements the interface, but when I call the method on the class it disagrees. Any ideas???

Comment: I think you'll need to provide more code or your actual code, this https://gist.github.com/davedevelopment/31b143fc44ec52fcc575 works as expected for me

Comment: I get this as well when using Mockery. I have found that running tests with process isolation enabled works (but this is noticeably slower).

Comment: I do remember having a similar problem which actually turned out to be a bug in Mockery. Can you update Mockery to dev-master and see if the problem still persists?

Answer (score 17):

You should call mock() method at the and of mock declaration.

```
$mock = Mockery::mock('MyNamespace\SomeSubFolder\MyInterface');

$mock->shouldReceive('method1')
     ->andReturn('foo')
     ->mock();
```

Comment: I'm also interested where this comes from. It's not mentioned anywhere in documentation. But my mocks basically *always* require this extra `->mock()` call.

Comment: Figured it out: I was wrongly chaining methods like `$mock = Mockery::mock(...)->shouldReceive();` which should actually be `$mock = ...; $mock->shouldReceive();`

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is with PHP class loading. Your 'MyNamespace\SomeSubFolder\MyInterface' class isn't available from your test file.

You'll need to modify your composer.json to autoload that namespace or you'll need a require_once('path/to/file/containing/namespace/MyInterface.php') at the top of your test.

Although, when you did try the interface_exists it seemed to pass. It could also be that you misspelled your namespaced class when you mocked it. I've made that mistake as well.

In any case, **Mockery isn't able to see that the class exists so it's just inventing one.**

Can you provide your full test source?

Comment: He's not using a constructor.