# Mocking interface with mockery?

Tags: php, phpunit, mockery

I am trying to create a mockery-mock for some interfaces in my tests.

But the result of the mocking is a mock-object that is not an instance of the interface. E.g. the generated mock-class does not ' implements MyInterface '.

I properly checked and found that Mockery CAN&DOES locate and load my interface (by adding some echo's in the mockery classes)

Is it really true that mockery does not declare that a mocked-class implements it requested interface?
Doesn't this completely bypass the good practices of TTD?

```
$mock = m::mock('My\\Cool\\Interface');
//now $mock is not aninstanceof My\Cool\Interface
```

Hope to hear from you.

Comment: can you check the result of interface_exists('My\\Cool\\Interface') just before the mock sentence?

Answer (score 3):

For a while I thought that mocking interfaces doesn't work for me as well but eventually I found a typo which caused the mock not to work.

At the moment mocking interfaces works for me.

Here is an example.

**Example Interface**

```
interface Convertor
{

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getIds();

}
```

**Creating the mock in phpunit test**

```
    $convertor = Mockery::mock('Convertor');
    $convertor->shouldReceive('getIds')->andReturn([10, 20]);
```

Can you post the code which doesn't work for you?

Comment: I think is talking about the case when you have:
`class A implements I {}

function tested(A $a) {
   if ($a instanceof I) {
      // do something
   }
}`
You can't make a Mock with Mockery to test this function

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question: yes, mockery does no proper job in implementing a mock-object for an interface.

To me, this kind of makes mockery useless for proper test-driven-development. :-(

Comment: Interface mocking works indeed. Please, take a look at @4ekistik response to a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/39545249/1085978

Comment: just mock the interace?